# Create encoding using C macros

Tags: c, macros, embedded

I have the following enumeration

```
typedef enum numbers_e {
    ZERO  = 0,
    ONE   = 1,
    TWO   = 2,
    THREE = 3,
} numbers_t;
```

I want to create a macro encoding(lets name the macro as GEN_ENCODING) in C to use in a case statement. Is this possible to do in C? if not, is there an alternative?

For example:

```
switch (encoding) {
    case GEN_ENCODING(TWO, ONE): //GEN_ENCODING should create 0x6
        do stuff ...
        break;
    case GEN_ENCODING(THREE, TWO, ONE): //GEN_ENCODING should create 0xE
        do stuff ...
        break;
    case GEN_ENCODING(THREE, TWO, ONE, ZERO): //GEN_ENCODING should create 0xF
        do stuff ...
        break;
}
```

Comment: Consider giving the macros values 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, ... and use bitwise or instead of preprocessor trickery.

Comment: The work required to 'iterate' over a variable length argument list in a macro and generate the correct value is considerable — it can be done (see Boost [Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor)), but it isn't worth it. The simple-minded techniques would allow `GEN_ENCODING(ONE, TWO, ZERO, THREE)` with elements out of sequence, and also `GEN_ENCODING(FOUR, FOUR, FOUR)` with repeated elements.  Eliminating such variations would be ridiculously hard.  How far would you extend it?  8 bits?  16 bits?  32 bits?  64 bits?  What do you think would be the benefit of using this scheme?

Comment: Thanks @FUZxxl , I am aware of making use of bit wise operator, but the requirement here is to keep the enumerations as they are.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler for the response. It is assumed that the user will provide the elements in sequence without repetition.

Comment: enum-constants are always type `int` that might cause problems for larger mask values (especially when you set the sign-bit). Consider using constant-like macros instead of the `enum` with appropriate type (e.g. `#define THIRTYTWOTHOUSANDSEVENHUNDREDSIXTYEIGHT (UINT32_C(1) << 15)` (noticed something?). Then follow @FUZxxl s advice.

Comment: @Olaf Did you seriously just suggested to make a macro named `THIRTYTWOTHOUSANDSEVENHUNDREDSIXTYEIGHT`?!

Comment: @FUZxxl: Sure! I use them all over the place. Remember: don't use magic **numbers** ... from my original comment: "(noticed something?)" - (and that's much the same as that nonsense hungarian notation like `u32WhyShouldIuseAnAppropriateName` with types) ... got it now? (hältst du mich echt für so blöd? ;-)